Mongoose populate() ref path problem in nest , in @nestjs/mongoose Prop decorator
Admin.name contains Admin refers to my Admin schema in nest I get Admin.name for ref and store in docModel same for User.name also
This is my chat model
@Schema({ timestamps: true, versionKey: false })
export class Chat {
  _id?: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

   @Prop({
   type: String,
   required: true,
   enum: [Admin.name, User.name],
   })
   docModel: string;

   @Prop({
   type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
   required: true,
   refPath: 'docModel',
   })

  @IsOptional()
  @IsMongoId()
  doc?: ObjectIdType;

}
when I populate on it
return this.chatModel
  .find(Query, {
    doc: 1,
   })
  .populate('doc', { name: 1, avatar: 1, rank: 1 })

my doc has no populate data only id it was returning
I have solved above question issue, name problem but still not work for me
any one with this can see my code and help me
Thank you for your help
